# wicket:link and pages with @AuthorizeInstantiation

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.6

I have a navigation bar like:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <wicket:link>
            <li><a href="Page1.html">Page1</a></li>
            <li><a href="Page2.html">Page2</a></li>
            <li><a href="Page3.html">Page3</a></li>
        </wicket:link>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This panel works really well (with the matching css).

But, `Page3` is only accessible for users logged in.

```
@AuthorizeInstantiation("SIGNED_IN")
public class Page3 extends MyPage {
    // ...
}
```

When a user is logged in, everything is as expected.

```
Navigation: Page1 Page2 Page3
```

But when the user is not logged in, I expect `Page3` not to be part of the navigation bar (because it is not accessible).

```
Navigation: Page1 Page2
```

How can I do this? TIA!

Answer (score 3):

Add your links using wicket. Then use IAuthorizationStrategy to check if you can instantiate the page the link refers to. Hide the link if not:

```
IAuthorizationStrategy strategy = getApplication().getSecuritySettings().getAuthorizationStrategy();
Link<?> page1link = new Link<Void>("page1") {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        setResponsPage(Page1.class);
    }
}
page1link.add(new Label("page1linklabel","Page 1"));
page1link.setVisible(strategy.isInstantiationAuthorized(Page1.class));
add(page1link);
```

The html for your link then looks like this:

```
<a href="#" wicket:id="page1"><span wicket:id="page1linklabel"></span></a>
```